# When installing several programs in a row, some needed my password, some didn't. Why?

Tags: password

When I was installing several programs from the Ubuntu Software Center, I installed several of them in a row; for some, I was asked to provide my password; for others, I wasn't. When I removed them, the same programs that needed a password for installation, needed a password for removal; the others didn't. Why is that?

I thought I needed to provide my password each time I make any changes. If not, doesn't my system become insecure? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you installing and removing them within minutes from each other? Software Center IIRC keeps your password for a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal. I also noticed it. The reason is when you first want to install a software, it ask for password, and you give it. The software center will grant you to install some more software for a short time,  it does so to make the installation process for the user more friendly. But since it also is a concern of security,  after this short time is expired, you will again be asked for password.

Same is true for uninstallation process. Hope I you got the point

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse when you provide password you have privileges until you shut down program (terminal, Ubuntu Software Center, etc.), or if you want after short amount of time.